# Volvo S40 T5 - No crank, no start - "Immobilizer See Manual"

Tags: starting

I changed the battery for My Volvo S40 T5. By mistake, I put the negative terminal to positive and a spark went up. The car then failed to start. It does not crank.

There is a message on the dash which says:

> IMMOBILIZER
>
> SEE MANUAL

I have tried all the tricks I found on the internet, but nothing has worked.

How do I fix this?

Comment: you're probably going to need to pull codes from the immobilizer computer to see why it's not allowing the start and go from there. if all your fuses are ok and re coding the key does't work you're going to have to have a professional with a scantool look at it.